# Al sacar el valor de un input text me aparece en blanco

Tags: javascript, html5

Al sacar el valor de un input text con .value el valor me aparece en blanco, me estoy reventando la cabeza y no logro entenderpor que ocurre. Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

```
<h1 id="titulo">
        Calculadora 1.0
    </h1><br><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="numero1" id="numero1">
    +
    <input type="text" name="numero2" id="numero2">
    <input type="submit" name="calcular" value="calcular" id="calcular"><br><br>
    <b>Resposta =</b> 
    <input type="text" name="result" id="result">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

```
let num1 = document.getElementById("numero1").value;
let num2 = document.getElementById("numero2").value;
let calcButton = document.getElementById("calcular");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

calcButton.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(num1);
    //console.log(num2);
}
```

Comment: Tienes que obtener el valor dentro de la función que se ejecuta en el click. De lo contrario el valor de esa variable será lo que sea que tu elemento tenia al momento de cargar el script.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo es bueno que coloques el input de resultado como tipo `number`, luego, los valores los tomas dentro de la función, siempre los toma como string, pues si tienes por ejemplo, que num1.value = 12 y num2.value = 13 cuando sumes te dará 1213. Lo que tienes que hacer es convertirlos en números(enteros o float). El código te quedaría así:

```js
let num1 = document.getElementById("numero1");
let num2 = document.getElementById("numero2");
// let calcButton = document.getElementById("calcular");
// let result = document.getElementById("result");
function calcButton() {

  result = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value);

  return data = document.getElementById('result').value = result;
  //console.log(num2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>InputStack</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="titulo">
    Calculadora 1.0
  </h1><br><br><br>
  <input type="number" name="numero1" id="numero1"> +
  <input type="number" name="numero2" id="numero2">
  <button onclick="calcButton()">Calcular</button>
  <!-- <input type="submit" name="calcular" value="calcular" id="calcular"><br><br> -->
  <b>Resposta =</b>
  <input type="number" name="result" id="result">

</body>

</html>
```